# Pandas: Achieving speed of 'built-in' methods (e.g. mean,std) for groups manipulations

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am working with a relative large `DataFrame` (~4M rows x 11 cols, numeric `ctypes`).

I need to do `groupby`-based manipulations, especially `transform`s and `aggregate`s. Approximately I'm working with `O(1M)` groups.

With my machine (i7 2600k, 8GB ram, Fedora20x64), I noticed that it's practically not possible to run any `groupby` manipulation than the 'built-in' ones.

E.g.

```
  df.groupby('key').Acol.mean()
```

takes a fraction of a second, whilst

```
  df.groupby('key').Acol.aggregate(pd.Series.mean)
```

can take minutes and memory consumption explodes.

Any other manipulation specified via a `lambda`, even if written in terms of `pd.Series` vectorizations, takes much more than I can afford to wait, or reaches crazy swapping levels.

**Q:** do you have any suggestion to get closer to performances of the "built-in" methods?

Can I somehow write my methods as the builtins are written? Can cython help?

---

The situation somehow gets worse when passing from `aggregate` to `transform`.

Thereby I couldn't find 'built-in' functions (Am I missing something??)

**What I am doing to tackle the problem**:

I split the `df` in several pieces (in a data-safe way), store them in `hdf5` files, load them from 4 clients, manipulate the data in parallel, re-save in `'hdf5'` and finally merge the result in the final `df`. This solution either works, or generates extreme swapping from the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses constant memory, and is O(number of groups).

The built in function have massive speedups for 2 reasons.

- They don't construct a nice object to compute the built in, as an index is not needed
- They don't have to go from cython space to python space (and back).

Thus in a non-trivial computation it is essential that you use the built in functions. Using (apply/aggregate) is nice for a generalized function evaluation, but pandas cannot make too many assumptions about what is going on in the user function, and these are evaluated in python space.

```
In [28]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4000000,11))

In [29]: df.groupby(df.index//4).ngroups
Out[29]: 1000000

In [30]: %timeit df.groupby(df.index//4).mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 412 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit -n 1 df.groupby(df.index//4).apply(lambda x: x.mean())
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 22s per loop
```

Passing `.aggregates(pd.Series.mean)` is de-facto `.apply(lambda x: x.mean())` and incurs the same perf penalty.

You should always use the vectorized built-ins whenever possible, esp with a large number of groups.

Here's an example of something which is not built in but can easily be achieved:

I want to compute max-min, so naively you should do:

```
df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

Much faster to do:

```
g = df.groupby(...)
g.max()-g.min()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
Don't get me wrong, but in your last example you could easily refactor your expression in vectorized form made via builtins.
My point was: can I use the same implementing strategy of builtins and build mine?

Consider for instance: `df.groupby(['Day_id','Frame']).apply(lambda x : x[x.Avg_U > 0].Speed.mean())` or `df.groupby(['Day_id','Frame']).transform(lambda x :len(x))`, I couldn't find yet a smarter vectorized form.

Comment: filter first, ``df[df.Avg_U>0].groupby(...).Speed.mean()``; for the 2nd, do this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496

Comment: Sounds cool, thanks, in both cases I need some lessons in index rearrangement...
Could you please give me an idea on how to "`zip`" the results from the first and the second operation? i.e. how can I have the size of each group and the mean value? (there can possibly be dis-homogeneities in the indices as in the first case I can have less groups than in the second one)...

Comment: actually you can use ``df.groupby(...).tranform('count')`` to get cythonized speed

Comment: that's what ``transform`` does

Comment: thanks, I am trying `df.groupby(...).transform('count')`. This is an interesting suggestion which somehow I missed from the reference. Anyway it looks slower than the builtin on groups, as that one takes milliseconds, while in this case I've been waiting for 10 minutes and memory consumption keeps on increasing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: wait, is [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7421) already in what i get from `pip` or shall I compile the latest master from gh? thanks

Comment: you need to use the lastest from master for the transform speedup